# Nextjs You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js

I'm using **nextjs** routing system and I want to `import` as other names like this :

```
import { Link as NavLink } from 'next/link';

const Link = ({ to, nav, children, ...props }) => {
    const { exact, activeClassName } = props;
    return (
        <NavLink href={to} rel="noopener noreferrer">
            {children}
        </NavLink>
    );
};

export default Link;
```

but it keeps returning this error! Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Link` is not a named export from `next/link` so you can't import it that way - `next/link` exports a default component which is commonly imported as `Link`. You need to import that default export (which means no brackets) and you can then technically name it whatever you want as your imported variable.

```js
import NavLink from 'next/link'

const Link = ({ to, nav, children, ...props }) => {
  // Use NavLink here
  ...
}

export default Link
```